# using shutil.copyfile I get a Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, permission-denied, shutil

I have some python code using shutil.copyfile:

```
import os
import shutil

src='C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\FilesPy'
des='C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\\tryPy\Output'

x=os.listdir(src)
a=os.path.join(src,x[1])

shutil.copyfile(a,des)
print a
```

It gives me an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\tryPy\\Output'
```

Why don't I have permission to copy the file?

Comment: shutil.copyfile will be run using the permissions of the user who ran the script.  Either run the python script using sudo or run it as root or use a different library that can do a copy and elevate itself to root if needed.

Comment: You can see this solution : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53894504/9533909](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53894504/9533909) solved my same problem

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) of `shutil.copyfile`:

> Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named src to a file named
>   dst. dst must be the complete target file name; look at shutil.copy()
>   for a copy that accepts a target directory path. If src and dst are
>   the same files, Error is raised. The destination location must be
>   writable; otherwise, an IOError exception will be raised. If dst
>   already exists, it will be replaced. Special files such as character
>   or block devices and pipes cannot be copied with this function. src
>   and dst are path names given as strings.

So I guess you need to either use [`shutil.copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) or add the file name to `des`:

```
des = os.path.join(des, x[1])
```

Comment: oh thank you i feel so stupid now..
now im expecting an IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\tryPy\\Output\\blatwo.docx'

Comment: @DrDark I'm not sure about the reason, but that probably means it can't find the `Output` folder. Try `open('C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\tryPy\\Output\\blatwo.docx', 'w')`: will it produce the same error?

Comment: the thing is that the path you mantioned is the output folder so its a little weird that it says it can't find the file or directory. you have any idea what to do ? : O

Comment: @DrDark check that the folder exists and its name doesn't have special characters. That's all Ican think of for now. If it doesn't help, maybe post a new question? with relevant code and error message

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the things here, but the issue with my code was regarding the permission of the destination folder. I created my own function for creating dir,

```
def mkdirs(newdir,mode=777):
    try:
        os.makedirs(newdir, mode)
    except OSError as err:
        return err
```

Instead of 777, later I used '0o777' the octal value, and later used `shutil.copyfile(target_file,dest_file)` and it worked !

Hope this helps someone, who is first creating the dir and then copying the file in it.

Answer (score 4):

I advice you rather use `shutil.copyfile` rather than `shutil.copy` if you can.

With `shutil.copyfile`, you have to consider metadata such as writing permission.