# Can´t copy file using shutils. Errno 13

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I´m trying to copy a json file from downloads to my folder. But I keep getting this error:

```
copyfile("C:/Users/pablo/Downloads/kaggle.json", "C:/Users/juan/.kaggle/")
```

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/juan/.kaggle/'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278066/using-shutil-copyfile-i-get-a-python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

copyfile need as the first argument the input **file** and as second argument the output **file**. 
You have a `/` at the end of the output file argument, so python think it is a directory.

If you want to copy the "C:/Users/pablo/Downloads/kaggle.json" file to the directory ".kaggle" then you need to put the filename at the end of the output file argument.

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile("C:/Users/pablo/Downloads/kaggle.json", "C:/Users/juan/.kaggle/kaggle.json")
```