# Copying Large Amount of File : Permission Error in Python

Tags: python

This is a simple copy file problem and I came here with my solution. There are some questions in Stackoverflow that are not closed as my problem. That's why I opened this.

Explanation:

Python gives errors while copying files, in my case I tried to copy the image data set to another file(318MB). Python gives these errors in random sequence.

**Data Set**:  [Data](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia)
**Python Version**: 3.8.13
**IDE**: VSCode

**Code and Error Message:**

```
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(imageData, "*.jpeg")):
   shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

> C:/Users/user1/Desktop/imageData Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\user1\Desktop\copyImageJPEG.py", line 35, in 
> shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)    File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py",
> line 418, in  copy
> copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)   File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py",
> line 264, in  copyfile
> with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'C:/Users/user1/Desktop/copyFolder\person110_virus_207.jpeg'

What I've done till now,

1. Gave permission access with [chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36745806/19592429)
2. [Tried to copy , copyFile, copy2 functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32966461/19592429)

[Also this ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280449/19592429)

3. [Wrote full path for both source and destination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518128/19592429)
4. Encoded the path for both source and destination
5. Run the python code [as Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13207450/19592429)

[Also this ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52452024/19592429)

6. [r-prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13207548)

Those solutions did not work for my problem. For those who can't find a solution like me, here is another solution:

Just close the copyFolder, don't disrupt it. In my case, I got the error while trying to see the last copied image, so the error popped up 50th, 100th, 150th, etc., depending on my check time.
Somehow the operating system blocks the code while we are using the folder.

I will update this post if I get another solution or the real reason for this disruption.

**Edit:** @Barmar Windows locks files while they're open in an editor. You get an error if you try to overwrite the locked file.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518067/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-im-copying-file

Comment: @Shrinidhi Hegde  It's one of my links, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Is the path with the error the source or destination?

Comment: If it's the destination, make sure you have write permission to the folder. And if the destination files already exist, ensure that you have write permission to those files.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's caused by destination because I got the error at different times after I open the destination folder.

Comment: @Barmar By the way, I got no error if I don't open the file. :) (strange)

Comment: You think? You can see the full pathname in the error message, is that the source or destination?

Comment: Windows locks files while they're open in an editor. You get an error if you try to overwrite the locked file.

Comment: You can put `try/except` around it to skip the files that can't be written.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah that's my I mean, its destination.

Comment: Is there any way to unlock it?